# Psych::BadAlias: Unknown alias: 1 when running rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psych

Something strange is happening with my application when I boot the jobs server with rake jobs:work. The rails webserver boots fine. I've noticed threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664614/rails4-psychbadalias-unknown-alias-test), however 1) it's not quite the same error message, that one seems more straightforward and 2) the answer did not yield any different results.

Here's my stacktrace -

```
rake aborted!
Psych::BadAlias: Unknown alias: 1
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:77:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:35:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:35:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:17:in `load_dj'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:85:in `payload_object'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:74:in `name'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:245:in `job_say'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:272:in `handle_failed_job'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `block in run'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `rescue in run'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:202:in `run'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:280:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:280:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:187:in `block in work_off'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `times'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `work_off'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:149:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `loop'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `block in start'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:146:in `start'
/Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue after `ruby` upgrade from `2.1.5` to `2.3.8`. Thats latest ruby version that could be run with rails `4.1.8`.

Upgrading to the latest version of `delayed_job` did not help. Also tried to specify downgraded version of [`psych`](https://github.com/ruby/psych) gem in my `Gemfile`. This did work not as well.

The real issue is that if error appears on job parsing stage then `delayed_job` does not update `last_error` column.

So I just went though all the jobs and checked if it could be parsed or not:

```
failing_jobs = []

Delayed::Job.find_each do |job|
  begin
    # this code is from dj source https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb#L15
    yaml = job.handler
    result = Psych.parse(yaml)
    result ? Delayed::PsychExt::ToRuby.create.accept(result) : result
  rescue Psych::BadAlias => e
    failing_jobs << job    
  end
end
```

In my case it were 6 jobs out of ~3k that could be deleted safely so I got lucky :)

Refs:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/867

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/pull/65